# CSP for angular

Tags: asp.net, angular, content-security-policy

I am implementing CSP for an Angular + ASP project. Since we have to run dynamic js files, I am trying to implement script-src with "strict-dynamic".

So far I implemented with a static nonce (which obviously is not good practice):

1. Added **script-src 'strict-dynamic' 'nonce-RandomNumber'** to my csp policy inside startup.cs file.
2. Published the project by **dotnet publish  -c Release -o publish**
3. Edited my index file in **publish/ClientApp/index.html** by adding **nonce=RandomNumber** to all the bundled script files

This is working. My question is that:

1. How can I automate this process and publish my project?
2. How can have an automated process which performs similarly but with dynamic nonces? or an automated process which instead of using nonces, reads the bundled hashes from compiled angular project and updates my policies inside startup.cs file?